# Why I obtain this error message when I try to add the TomCat installation into NetBeans on Ubuntu (The CATALINA_HOME /conf/server.xml can't be read)?

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I have installed TomCat 8 on an Ubuntu 15.04 system and I have to use **NetBeans**

Now the problem is when I try to add my **TomCat 8** installation into NetBeans (into Window --> Services --> Servers --> Add Server).  After that, when I select my TomCat directory it gives me the following error message:

> **The CATALINA_HOME /conf/server.xml can't be read.**

Why? What does it mean? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to read this file from a different program using the same user account ? Is the file there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **CATALINA_HOME** may not be correct.Please Correct your **CATALINA_HOME** using `export` command.